# Memory access failure in my RNG function, while using memcpy

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm getting a memory access failure while i try to copy the element from my random array.
I have no clue what i am doing wrong, thx for your help in advance.

Here is my code:

```
  1 #include <TSS_API_RNG.h>
  2
  3 using namespace std;
  4
  5 // dummy rng for internal speed tests
  6 void rng(uint8_t out[], size_t len) {
  7
  8    unsigned char iv[len];
  9    size_t i, k;
 10    srand(time(NULL));
 11      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 12      k = rand()%256;
 13      iv[i] = (unsigned char)k;
 14      cout << iv[i] << endl;
 15
 16      memcpy(&out[0], &iv[0], len);
 17      cout << &out[0] << endl;
 18      memset(&iv[0], 0x00, len);
 19   }
 20 }
 21
 22 int main() {
 23
 24    rng(NULL, 10);
 25    return 0;
 26 }
```

And this is what happens when i try to execute my programme:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/projects/RNG_final $ ./DUMMY_RNG
▒
Speicherzugriffsfehler
```

I must be using the `memcopy` function not correctly, but i have no idea how to solve this issue. For testing i wanted to pass 10 random numbers, but it fails at the first iteration of `memcpy`. The loop itselfe works properly, hence it prints the value in the first `cout` value correctly.

Comment: Tell me, in `memcpy(&out[0], &iv[0], len);`, what does `&out[0]` point to?

Comment: `NULL` is NOT a right place to write something.

Comment: Note that `srand` / `rand` do not provide very good quality random numbers (and `time(NULL)` is a terrible seed - and you should only seed the generator *once*, not on every call to your function). You may want to investigate the modern random facilities in the [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header / library. Also, maybe watch [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) - it's a good talk.

Comment: The last `memset(&iv[0], 0x00, len);` in `rng` makes *no sense* - everything you are working with there is going to go out of scope when the function ends, so why are you even bothering with that line? It is pointless.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, yes i know it's i bad. The purpose is to have an as primitive rng as possible. Because i want to measure performance differences in random number fetch times from Botan::MC-Eliece when it gehts it's random numbers from within the system in comparison to a TSS API TPM 2.0.

Perhaps you are right and i will have to change the rng type anyway, hence mc-eliece has rnq quality requirements, which srand might not match.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Obligatory *VLA* warning. `unsigned char iv[len];` is not legal C++. In C++ array bounds must be compile time constants.

Comment: @john it's not very portable, but `gcc` in particular allows variable size arrays as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Thx guys, managed to fix the issue with your advice.

My code:

```
  1 #include <TSS_API_RNG.h>
  2
  3 using namespace std;
  4
  5 // constructor
  6 DUMMY_RNG::DUMMY_RNG()
  7   :r_len(0), r_count(0)
  8 {
  9    std::cout << "Neue Instanz" << std::endl;
 10 }
 11
 12
 13 // destructor
 14 DUMMY_RNG::~DUMMY_RNG(void)
 15 {
 16 }
 17
 18
 19 // dummy rng for internal speed tests
 20 int DUMMY_RNG::rng(uint8_t out[], size_t len) {
 21
 22    unsigned char iv[len];
 23    size_t k;
 24    srand(time(NULL));
 25      //for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 26      k = rand()%256;
 27      iv[0] = (unsigned char)k;
 28
 29      memcpy(&out[0], &iv[0], len);
 30      memset(&iv[0], 0x00, len);
 31   //}
 32     return 1;
 33 }
 34
 35
 36 // randomize function replacement from botan rng class
 37 void DUMMY_RNG::randomize(uint8_t out[], size_t len)
 38 {
 39    r_count += 1;
 40    r_len += len;
 41
 42    rng(out, len);
 43 }
```